# textbox validation in lift

Tags: validation, scala, textbox, lift

How can I perform a text validation on a textbox in form written in lift?
For example I have this form code:

```
def render = ".name" #> SHtml.text(name, name = _) &
".destination" #> SHtml.text(destination, destination = _) &
".phone" #> SHtml.text(phone, phone = _) &
":submit" #> SHtml.onSubmitUnit(() =>
```

How can I add validation to those text boxes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make all validations in function that is passed to `onSubmitUnit`. Simply Lift [Forms chapter](http://stable.simply.liftweb.net/#toc-Section-4.2) have a lot of nice examples of form processing.

Comment: I tried writing S.error in the function I send to onSubmitUnit, but it seems like it does nothing, just refreshes the page. Do you know what is wrong here?

Comment: It is normal behavior. `S.error` just sets an error messages, which can be shown in `<div class="lift:Msgs"/>` and nothing more.